# Grand Central Dispatch for complex flow?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch, completionhandler

I have **a, b, c, d, e** time consuming task functions with completion handler.

There are constraints between them:

1. Both **b** & **c** wait for **a** to finish
2. The last task **e** waits for **b** & **c** & **d** to finish

[image]

if there is no task **d**, I could write code in swift like this (not tested yet)

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

group.enter()
a() { group.leave() }
group.wait()

group.enter()
b() { group.leave() }

group.enter()
c() { group.leave() }

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    e()
}
```

How to add task **d** without waiting **a** to complete?

---

Edited on 4/30 10:00 (+8)

**Code Different** said

> the easiest approach is to make the download function synchronous and add a warning to its documentation that it should never be called from the main thread.

So I made a version based on it. This way cannot handle the return values from concurrent calls. But it looks really like async/await. So I'm satisfied now. Thank you guys.

the async/await like part is

```
    myQueue.async {
        downloadSync("A")
        downloadSync("B", isConcurrent: true)
        downloadSync("C", isConcurrent: true)
        downloadSync("D", 4, isConcurrent: true)
        waitConcurrentJobs()
        downloadSync("E")
    }
```

And the full code is below.

```
    let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
    let myQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "for Sync/Blocking version of async functions")

    func waitConcurrentJobs() {
        myGroup.wait()
    }

    // original function (async version, no source code)
    func download(_ something: String, _ seconds: UInt32 = 1, completionHandler: @escaping ()->Void = {}) {
        print("Downloading \(something)")
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            sleep(seconds)
            print("\(something) is downloaded")
            completionHandler()
        }
    }

    // wrapped function (synced version)
    // Warning:
    // It blocks current thead !!!
    // Do not call it on main thread
    func downloadSync(
        _ something: String,
        _ seconds: UInt32 = 1,
        isConcurrent: Bool = false
        ){
        myGroup.enter()
        download(something, seconds) { myGroup.leave() }
        if !isConcurrent {
            myGroup.wait()
        }
    }

    // Now it really looks like ES8 async/await
    myQueue.async {
        downloadSync("A")
        downloadSync("B", isConcurrent: true)
        downloadSync("C", isConcurrent: true)
        downloadSync("D", 4, isConcurrent: true)
        waitConcurrentJobs()
        downloadSync("E")
    }
```

results

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just have to ask, why not use Operations and dependencies. Operations do live on top of GCD and dependencies are there to take care of exactly that of what you ask.

Comment: Because I never heard of them. I’m working on my first Swift app (switched from react native) Thanks~ I will google them. :-)

Comment: Operation in Swift is part of Foundation API from Apple. It used to be NSOperation, but has been renamed to Operation some time ago. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation

Comment: If you have to pass results from pervious task(s) to the next task(s), using `Operation` will become pretty complex and cumbersome (== error prone) because you need to synchronise the data transfer (again using dispatch queues for example).

Comment: Please watch https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/226/

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** the easiest approach is to make the `download` function synchronous and add a warning to its documentation that it should never be called from the main thread. The pyramid of doom for async function is the reason why [coroutines were proposed](https://gist.github.com/lattner/429b9070918248274f25b714dcfc7619), by no other than Chris Lattner, Swift's creator. As of April 2018, it's not yet a formal proposal waiting for review so chances are that you won't see it in Swift 5.

An synchronous download function:

```
// Never call this from main thread
func download(_ something: String, _ seconds: UInt32 = 1, completionHandler: @escaping ()->Void = {}) {
    let group = DispatchGroup()

    print("Downloading \(something)")
    group.enter()
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        sleep(seconds)
        print("\(something) is downloaded")
        completionHandler()
        group.leave()
    }
    group.wait()
}
```

And `NSOperation` / `NSOperationQueue` setup:

```
let opA = BlockOperation() {
    self.download("A")
}
let opB = BlockOperation() {
    self.download("B")
}
let opC = BlockOperation() {
    self.download("C")
}
let opD = BlockOperation() {
    self.download("D", 4)
}
let opE = BlockOperation() {
    self.download("E")
}

opB.addDependency(opA)
opC.addDependency(opA)

opE.addDependency(opB)
opE.addDependency(opC)
opE.addDependency(opD)

let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
operationQueue.addOperations([opA, opB, opC, opD, opE], waitUntilFinished: false)
```

Comment: a, b, c, d here actually are some async functions. Does this way support async functions like network request?

Comment: I found it is not working with async functions. See the edited post.

Comment: Thank you~ I made a version based on your  suggestions. It looks great :-)

Comment: I finally decided to downvote this solution, because it's not scaleable  through wasting precious resources by creating a thread per operation and since there are solutions which actually avoid this. I upvote again when we have coroutines ;)

Comment: I assume you have some benchmark to back up the claim?

Comment: While it varies greatly on different systems, on MacOS and iOS threads are based on mach tasks. These are system resources and quite expensive. Overuse can slow down the whole system. This was (also) a reason to invent GCD. On iOS there's a limit (probably a soft limit) how many threads you can create per process. You can create a  test yourself easily to figure out the number (just call an async function in a loop). Last time I checked, it was less than 100.

Comment: For further reference regarding the costs of threads: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html

Answer (score 0):

Your original effort seems very close to me. You could make a minor adjustment: make `B`, `C`, and `D` be the group that finishes to trigger `E`.

`A` could be another group, but since it's one task, I don't see the point. Trigger `B` and `C` when it's done.

Note that unlike some of the example code in your question and other answers, in the code below, `D` and `A` can both start right away and run in parallel.

```
let q = DispatchQueue(label: "my-queue", attributes: .concurrent)
let g = DispatchGroup()
func taskA() {  print("A")  }
func taskB() {  print("B"); g.leave()  }
func taskC() {  print("C"); g.leave()  }
func taskD() {  print("D"); g.leave()  }
func taskE() {  print("E")  }
g.enter()
g.enter()
g.enter()
q.async {
    taskA()
    q.async(execute: taskB)
    q.async(execute: taskC)
}
q.async(execute: taskD)
g.notify(queue: q, execute: taskE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this framework to implement async/await pattern - https://github.com/belozierov/SwiftCoroutine

When you call await it doesn’t block the thread but only suspends coroutine, so you can use it in the main thread as well.

```
func awaitAPICall(_ url: URL) throws -> String? {
    let future = URLSession.shared.dataTaskFuture(for: url)
    let data = try future.await().data
    return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
}

func load(url: URL) {
    DispatchQueue.main.startCoroutine {
        let result1 = try self.awaitAPICall(url)
        let result2 = try self.awaitAPICall2(result1)
        let result3 = try self.awaitAPICall3(result2)
        print(result3)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would like to show an alternative solution using Scala like futures:

```
let result = funcA().flatMap { resultA in
    return [funcB(param: resultA.0),
            funcC(param: resultA.1),
            funcD()]
        .fold(initial: [String]()) { (combined, element) in
            return combined + [element]
    }
}.flatMap { result in
    return funcE(param: result)
}.map { result in
    print(result)
}
```

That's it basically. It handles errors (implicitly) and is thread-safe. No Operation subclasses  ;)

Note, that `funcD` will be called only when A completes successfully. Since `funcA()` can fail it would make no sense to call it. But the code can be easily adapted to make this possible as well, iff required.

Please compare this to function `foo()` from my other solution which uses Dispatch Groups and Dispatch Queues.

Below an example of the definitions of the async functions which each passing their result to the next one:

```
func funcA() -> Future<(String, String)> {
    print("Start A")
    let promise = Promise<(String, String)>()
    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
        print("Complete A")
        promise.complete(("A1", "A2"))
    }
    return promise.future
}

func funcB(param: String) -> Future<String> {
    print("Start B")
    let promise = Promise<String>()
    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        print("Complete B")
        promise.complete("\(param) -> B")
    }
    return promise.future
}

func funcC(param: String) -> Future<String> {
    print("Start C")
    let promise = Promise<String>()
    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        print("Complete C")
        promise.complete("\(param) -> C")
    }
    return promise.future
}

func funcD() -> Future<String> {
    print("Start D")
    let promise = Promise<String>()
    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4) {
        print("Complete D")
        promise.complete("D")
    }
    return promise.future
}

func funcE(param: [String]) -> Future<String> {
    print("Start E")
    let promise = Promise<String>()
    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4) {
        print("Complete E")
        promise.complete("\(param) -> E")
    }
    return promise.future
}
```

Which prints this to the console:

`Start A
Complete A
Start B
Start C
Start D
Complete B
Complete C
Complete D
Start E
Complete E
["A1 -> B", "A2 -> C", "D"] -> E`

Hint: there are a couple of Future and Promise libraries available.

Comment: Sorry I still struggle to understand flatMap or ... Why funcA is different to others? What's library for Promise and Future here?

Comment: For scala like futures you use `flatMap` (basically) when the completion function returns another future. You use `map`when it straight returns a result (i.e. either a value or an error). `map` returns a future of the result of the completion function, where flatmap returns a future that gets resolved with the eventual result of the future returned by the completion function.

Comment: For scala like futures I would recommend BrightFutures (on github). But there are really a couple more that look decent. The advantage with Scala like futures is, that they are really powerful and yield concise code. It may take a while to understand the functional paradigm behind it (map, flatMap and other combinators), though.